# How to avoid overlapping HTML tags to highlight text

Tags: html, css

In the code below, I have three hover texts and the world "hello". The first two highlight parts of "hello", and I want the 3rd to highlight all of "hello". Wrapping all the first two spans in a 3rd span doesn't work, and I understand why. I know that I cannot overlap HTML tags, and I don't know if nesting is the solution.

How would you set this up so that the third hover works?

http://jsfiddle.net/CAWhP/3/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="test1"> highlight hel in hello</div>

<div id="test2"> highlight lo in hello</div>

<div id="test3"> highlight all of hello</div>

<span class="testspan1"> hel</span><span class="testspan2">lo </span>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#test1:hover ~ .testspan1{

   background: red;
}

#test2:hover ~ .testspan2{

   background: red;
}
#test3:hover ~ .testspan3{

   background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the relevant element

```
#test3:hover ~ span{
   background: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CAWhP/5/)

Or else you can also use this

```
#test3:hover ~ span.testspan1, #test3:hover ~ span.testspan2 {
   background: red;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/CAWhP/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do this, but to solve the problem, I guess you could do this:

```
#test3:hover ~ .testspan1,
#test3:hover ~ .testspan2 {
   background: red;
}
```

**Complete and shorter version:**

Since all rules apply the same property, you could shorten your complete CSS to this:

```
#test1:hover ~ .testspan1,
#test2:hover ~ .testspan2,
#test3:hover ~ .testspan1,
#test3:hover ~ .testspan2
{
   background: red;
}
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/CAWhP/6/)

Comment: Chris, I've created a site where I can highlight some text, right click, and add a div. When I hover over the div, it highlights that text by inserting HTML tags to reference the correct css. The problem is that when I highlight part of the same text, it creates overlapping tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAWhP/4/)

```
#test3:hover ~ .testspan1 {

background: red;

}

#test3:hover ~ .testspan2 {

background: red;

}
```

You could also separate the classes with commas, like `#test3:hover ~ .testspan1, #test3:hover ~ .testspan2`. That would work if you want both spans to have the same style.